# What do gems do?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I found a ruby and sapphire when blowing up some rocks. The shopkeepers offer me a lot of rupees for them, but I don't want to sell them if they are needed for other things, like equipment upgrades.

Do these gems have any other purpose other than making money?

Comment: Since I don't have the game I can't check for sure, but it seems gems are used for [crafting certain weapons of specific types](https://rankedboost.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild/crafting-materials/).  For example, using a ruby makes a fire weapon.  That and selling them.  I've read that you do not want to sell any diamonds you find as they are rarer and have different uses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gems seem to serve three primary purposes:

- Being worth a boatload of money.
- Being used as an upgrade component.
- Being able to made into accessories.

Some items, like the Berserker set, require 2 diamonds to upgrade. There are likely other sets like this, but I'm uncertain.

As Sam mentioned, you can also use gems to get circlets and earrings from the Gerudo Jeweler. They take up a head slot (so they're not particularly useful in most cases) and there are 6 total:

- Amber (8 amber = +4 def earrings)
- Opal (8 opals = swim speed boost earrings)
- Ruby (5 rubies = ice resist up circlet)
- Sapphire (5 sapphires = fire resist up circlet)
- Diamond (3 diamonds = guardian resist circlet)
- Topaz (5 topaz = electric resist earrings)

This is of course only doable after you give her the 10 Flint.

Comment: Hmm, they do seem kinda useful then, to a point. Some of them seem fairly common, so it probably cant hurt to sell some of them

Comment: @BenCraig admittedly, I sold all of mine. The head pieces are completely useless when you get set bonuses from other equipment, though if you go to the Gerudo town first, they might be much more valuable. It was my third place, so by then I had already had very good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I saw in the Gerudo town that there is a jeweler that offers to make strength enhancing jewelry using them for the exchange of some flint (10) and a little cash. I'm keeping them on hand until I can investigate the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

A really good tip (it might be already known but i hope i may say it here too is that Diamonds are used to re-forge the 4 weapons/shield that we get from bosses.
Aswell as upgrading certain parts of gear as noted previously here.

The ways ive found so far is to give 10 luminos stones to the zora by the entrance (green one)

And also giving 55 rushrooms to a Pirou at Gerudo canyon stable.

Personally i never miss a ore deposit for the chance of diamonds.